# Flutter code auto-formatting-on-save in Vscode is different than running "dart format .\lib\main.dart". How to change this?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, format

Hello Flutter community,

As the question indicates, when I use the auto-format-on-save in Vscode, the code is formatted in a strange way as shown below:
[image]

However, when I use the terminal command "dart format .\lib\main.dart" or "flutter format .\lib\main.dart" it is formatted in much clearer way as shown below (notice the appBar widget formatting):

[image]

How can I change the behaviour of auto-format-on-save to work the same way as "dart format .\lib\main.dart" or "flutter format .\lib\main.dart"?

The project folder settings.json file content is:

```
"[dart]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Looks like the difference is in where the Dart formatter's maximum line length?   Try setting `"dart.lineLength": 80`.

Comment: Thank you very much that solves the issue :)